# expl3 switch for booleans: Is there a \bool_case:Nnn?

Tags: conditionals, latex3, expl3

There's `\int_case:Nnn`, `\tl_case:Nnn`, `\str_case:Nnn`, but I can't find something like `\bool_case:Nnn`.

I know I can write:

```
\bool_if:NT \l__<mymodule>_<nameA>_bool { ... }
\bool_if:NT \l__<mymodule>_<nameB>_bool { ... }
\bool_if:NT \l__<mymodule>_<nameC>_bool { ... }
\bool_if:NT \l__<mymodule>_<nameD>_bool { ... }
```

to achieve something of the same effect, or even

```
\bool_if:NTF \l__<mymodule>_<nameA>_bool 
{
   <some code>
}
{
    \bool_if:NTF \l__<mydoclue>_<nameB>_bool
    {
        <some code>
    }
    {
        <continue nesting w/ default value in last *F*> 
    }
}
```

But the first example evaluates all the booleans and there is not clean way to have a default value if all fail.  The second example is just really clunky, difficult to read and hard to change if, for example, you later decide that the booleans should be tested in a different order.

Is there an alternative I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Well, booleans are true or false. You're thinking to something like `\elseif` which doesn't seem to fit in the model.

Comment: @egreg I know.  But I have a bunch of switches that are either on or off.  They're listed in a particular order, which ever of the earlier switches is first turned on should result in behavior just for that switch (regardless of the settings of later switches).  If none of the switches are turned on, then I want a default state.

Comment: @egreg I suppose I could set a `\tl_<variable>` with each switch and then do a `\tl_case:Nnn` on the values of the tokens.  But it seems like it would be cleaner if I could do it without having to nest or add a layer of something else to effect the testing.

Comment: Do you want something like `||`? *A boolean expression is an expression which given input in the form of predicate functions and boolean variables, return boolean ⟨true⟩ or ⟨false⟩. It supports the logical operations And, Or and Not as the well-known infix operators &&, || and ! with their usual precedences. In addition to this, parentheses can be used to isolate sub-expressions.*

Comment: One might encode a set of booleans in a number in binary form and then do a `\int_case:nnn` using this number.

Comment: @egreg I like that idea.  You want to write up a solution for that?

Comment: @A.Ellett Not in a short time.

Comment: @A.Ellett, I’ve proposed `\bool_case:nn` [here on the LaTeX3 mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.latex.latex3/3017). Joseph Wright has questioned the need for this, pointing out some differences between it and the other case functions. Would you care to post on the list and explain your use-case?

Comment: @J.C.Salomon I wouldn't mind putting in my two cents.  I followed the link, but I don't see how I can add further comments to the thread.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @A.Ellett Select the relevant message, then choose “Followup” from the drop-down menu in the upper-right-hand corner. You might also subscribe to the LATEX-L list; see latex-project.org/code.html for details.

Comment: BTW, the devs have suggested renaming the `*_case:Nnn` functions to `*_case:NnF` and adding `*_case:Nn` (and possibly `:NnTF` and `:NnT`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapting the code from `\tl_case:Nnn`, I have this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3, xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \bool_case:nn #1#2
  {
    \tex_romannumeral:D
      \__bool_case:w #1 \c_true_bool {#2} \q_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__bool_case:w #1#2
  {
    \bool_if:nTF { #1 }
      { \__bool_case_end:nw {#2} }
      { \__bool_case:w }
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \__bool_case_end:nw \__prg_case_end:nw

\bool_gset_false:N \g_tmpa_bool
\bool_gset_true:N \g_tmpb_bool

\NewDocumentCommand \testboolcase {} {
    \bool_case:nn {
        \g_tmpa_bool { false;~ can't~ happen }
        \g_tmpb_bool { true;~ should~ happen }
      }
      { else;~ can't~ happen }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \testboolcaseelse {} {
    \bool_case:nn {
        \g_tmpa_bool { false;~ can't~ happen }
        { !\g_tmpb_bool } { false;~ can't~ happen }
      }
      { else;~ should~ happen }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\testboolcase

\testboolcaseelse
\end{document}
```

Note that some boolean expressions work, but things like `{ 1 = 2 }` won’t.

Comment: Very nice.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Now to figure out why this does what it does.

Comment: @A.Ellett, that’s a new question: [_How do the `\xx_case:` functions work?_](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121390/2966)

Comment: Note that this is now `\bool_case:nn`, **not** `\bool_case:Nnn`. Numbers in the boolean expressions will confuse `\romannumeral`.

Comment: Unfortunately this code no longer compiles, it seems to be related to `\__prg_case_end:nw`. I have found use of a `\bool_case:nn` in a personal package. Will you update the answer or is it a new question?

Comment: @Simon, I’d suggest looking up the current version of `\tl_case:Nnn` and see if you can adapt the code accordingly—a new answer is probably the right way to go, unless the change to my code above is trivial. (I have not touched this in years and can’t follow it to fix it right now.)

Comment: @J.C.Salomon As of 2015-07-04 `\tl_case:Nnn` is deprecated. `\bool_case:nF` (evt. `nT`, `nTF`) based on `\tl_case:Nn` would be the way to go, and the changes is trivial (some minor changes to `\bool_case:nn` and `\__bool_case_end:nw`).

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm looking for something like

```
\bool_new:N \l_ae_a_bool
\bool_new:N \l_ae_b_bool
\bool_new:N \l_ae_c_bool
\bool_new:N \l_ae_d_bool

<intermediary code>

\bool_new:N \l_ae_continue_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_ae_continue_bool
\bool_if:NTF \l_ae_a_bool 
  { 
    <code-a> 
    \bool_set_false:N \l_ae_continue_bool %% here for just good measure!
  } 
  { 
     \bool_set_true:N \l_ae_continue_bool 
  }
\bool_if:NT \l_ae_continue_bool
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_ae_b_bool 
      {
        <code-b> 
        \bool_set_false:N \l_ae_continue_bool
      } 
      { 
        \bool_set_true:N \l_ae_continue_bool 
      }
  }
\bool_if:NT \l_ae_continue_bool
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_ae_c_bool 
      {
        <code-c> 
        \bool_set_false:N \l_ae_continue_bool
      } 
      { 
        \bool_set_true:N \l_ae_continue_bool 
      }
  }
\bool_if:NT \l_ae_continue_bool
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_ae_d_bool 
      {
        <code-d> 
        \bool_set_false:N \l_ae_continue_bool
      } 
      { 
        \bool_set_true:N \l_ae_continue_bool 
      }
  }
\bool_if:NF \l_ae_continue_bool
  {
    <default code>
  }
```

Comment: Is this a solution? If not please edit your original question and remove this one. Thanks

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It does what I want to accomplish.  So, I'd say it's a solution, but I was hoping someone could come up with something better.